# Work with database using Hibernate from JSP

Tags: hibernate, jsp, tomcat7

Hi guys,
I use:

```
Java EE 6
Tomcat 7
Hibernate 4.1.10.Final
Mysql-connector 5.1.10
Mysql 5.6.10
```

It's my first web-application with Hibernate. I want to add String value to my database using Hibernate. But, getting such error from Tomcat:

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /doPayment.jsp at line 73

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /doPayment.jsp at line 73

70: //            hiberUtil.saveDB(read);
71:             Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
72:             transaction.setTransaction(read);
73:             Factory.getInstance().getTransactionDAO().addTransaction(transaction);
74: 
75:             List<Transaction> transactions = Factory.getInstance().getTransactionDAO().getAllTransactions();
76:             System.out.println("========Р’СЃРµ С‚СЂР°РЅСЃР°РєС†РёРё=========");


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.doPayment_jsp._jspService(doPayment_jsp.java:167)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
    us.test.HiberUtil.<clinit>(HiberUtil.java:26)
    us.test.TransactionDAOImpl.addTransaction(TransactionDAOImpl.java:21)
    org.apache.jsp.doPayment_jsp._jspService(doPayment_jsp.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    us.test.HiberUtil.<clinit>(HiberUtil.java:26)
    us.test.TransactionDAOImpl.addTransaction(TransactionDAOImpl.java:21)
    org.apache.jsp.doPayment_jsp._jspService(doPayment_jsp.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

What can be a source of this error?

**Here is my JSP file:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<%

    Token tk = new Token();
    String read;
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String payerid = request.getParameter("PayerID");
    System.out.println(" Raw Token in DoPayment " + tk.raw_token);

    try {
        System.out.println("Sending form");
        URL url = new URL(tk.APIEndpoint);
        HttpURLConnection hConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
        hConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        hConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        String token = request.getParameter("TOKEN");
        System.out.println("Token in HttpURLConnection" + token);

        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(hConnection.getOutputStream());
        hConnection.connect();
        ps.print("USER=my_user&PWD=my_pwd&" +
                "SIGNATURE=my_signature&" +
                "VERSION=98.0&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=1.00&" +
                "PaymentActionSpecified=true&" +
                "PAYERID="+payerid+"&TOKEN=" + request.getParameter("token").replaceAll("-", "%2d") + "&" +
                "METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment");
        ps.close();

        System.out.println("Form sent");
        if(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == hConnection.getResponseCode()){
            System.out.println(hConnection.getContentType());
            InputStream is = hConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            read = br.readLine();

            while(read != null){
                sb.append(read);
                read = br.readLine();

            }

//            Save String to Database

            Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
            transaction.setTransaction(read);
            Factory.getInstance().getTransactionDAO().addTransaction(transaction);

            List<Transaction> transactions = Factory.getInstance().getTransactionDAO().getAllTransactions();
            System.out.println("========All transactions=========");
            for(int i = 0; i < transactions.size(); ++i) {
                System.out.println("Transaction : " + transactions.get(i).getTransaction());
                System.out.println("=============================");
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());

            hConnection.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Connection closed.");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


%>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is screenshot of my project:**

[image]

P.s. Please don't tell me that "it's bad idea to use scriplets in JSP" :) I understand it. Trying to understand from the very beging how it works and then will improve the code.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but Tomcat never was and it is not Java EE, is just a Servlet Container. A real Java EE application server is JBoss (built on top of Tomcat), GlassFish, IBM WebSphere, Oracle WebLogic, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration

This means that you're missing libraries in your project. On Java Web Applications, the third party libraries **must** go in *WEB-INF/lib* folder. If this folder doesn't exists, create it manually and drop your jars there. After doing this, rebuild and redeploy your application.

---

Not directly related to your main question:

- Tomcat never was and it is not Java EE, is just a Servlet Container. Some real Java EE application server are JBoss (built on top of Tomcat), GlassFish, IBM WebSphere, Oracle WebLogic. Just to let you know, there's [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html), another real Java EE 6 application server based on Tomcat (but again, it is not Tomcat).
- > P.s. Please don't tell me that "it's bad idea to use scriplets in JSP" :) I understand it. Trying to understand from the very beging how it works and then will improve the code.

  **Never** use scriptlets (better explained here: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)). If you know they're evil, then don't even dare to learn about it! It's like saying *I know poison is bad, but I will taste it anyway*. Learn the right way and start using MVC pattern as shown in [StackOverflow Servlets wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Answer (score 0):

Your error message does say `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration`, which means the Hibernate jar files are not in your application class path, put them at the right place and your code should proceed.